# Byte stream / C / JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

What data types are usually used in C API implementation for storing byte streams?
How can I convert this type to jbyteArray?

Answer (score 1):

That'd be (const) unsigned char * representing a block of memory holding the bytes themselves, coupled with a size_t telling you the number of bytes.

[This thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t148587-making-and-returning-java-byte-arrays-in-c-via-jni-help-please.html) seems to go over how to create a suitable Java type (NewByteArray() is the function).

Answer (score 1):

See the Java_ReadFile_loadFile example where they use NewByteArray() and return it directly.

http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/java/Books/JDCBook/jnistring.html

```
  JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_ReadFile_loadFile
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj, jstring name) {
      caddr_t m;
      jbyteArray jb;
      struct stat finfo;
      jboolean iscopy;
      const jchar *mfile = (*env)->GetStringChars(env, 
        name, &iscopy);
  //...
      (*env)->ReleaseStringChars(env, name, mfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear.

Assuming you have some bytes in C representing characters, the best idea is to get the bytes into Java and convert them to text there using Java's byte conversions.

In JNI you simply need to materialize a Java array, either by using JNI to instantiate one, or by passing a reference in as a parameter (for which you still need to "materialize" a pointer in the JNI code).

I have done this latter thing before, so here is the code FYI.  This JNI call used an AS/400 C API to read a database record and return the bytes back to Java - the Java code then used record format information to extract the fields into Strings.  Hope this is of some help:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_xxx_DB2File_jniRead(JNIEnv *jep, jobject thsObj,                    
 jlong handle, jint readOp, jbyteArray jvaDta, jint jvaDtaMax, jint flags) {                                                
    OBJDTA           *odp;                                                                                                  
    jbyte            *jniDta;                                                                                               
    _RIOFB_T         *fbp;                                                                                                  

    thsObj=thsObj;                                                                                                          
    if((odp=getDataspace(handle))==NULL) {                                                                                  
        throwEscape(jep,90003,"Invalid handle for dataspace in jniRead()");                                                 
        return JNI_FALSE;                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                   
    jniDta=(*jep)->GetByteArrayElements(jep,jvaDta,0);                                                                      

    // read database record here

    if(fbp->num_bytes<=0) {                                                                                                 
        (*jep)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jep,jvaDta,jniDta,JNI_ABORT); /* do not copy changed array back to java */         
        return JNI_FALSE;                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                   
    if(fbp->num_bytes!=odp->rcdLen) {                                                                                       
        byte             errtxt[201];                                                                                       

        asd_errtxt(errno,errtxt,sizeof(errtxt));                                                                            
        (*jep)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jep,jvaDta,jniDta,JNI_ABORT); /* do not copy changed array back to java */         
        throwEscape(jep,90204,"Native function jniRead failed.  Got %i, expected %i (%s)",fbp->num_bytes,odp->rcdLen,       
         errtxt);                                                                                                           
        return JNI_FALSE;                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                   
    (*jep)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jep,jvaDta,jniDta,0); /* copy changed array back to java */                            
    return JNI_TRUE;                                                                                                        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert them. The types jbyteArray and char* are compatible.

Java declaration:

```
private static native int doSomething(bate[] string, int length);
```

C delaration:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_package_class_doSomething(JNIEnv *env, jclass jc, jbyteArray string, jint length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // read string[i]
    }
}
```

You can pass values back to java the same way. But make sure the length of the byte array is initialized BEFORE calling the C function.